# How to get list of all logged in users using

Tags: c#, windows

How can I get a list of usernames and their activity times on a remote machine, using C#?

For example, if there is a Windows machine named 'ABC-PC' and there are currently three active users on it named 'X', 'Y' and 'Z'. Where:

- 'X' is currently active
- 'Y' is idle for last 4 minutes
- 'Z' is idle for last 20 minutes

I want to write code that fetches me all of these mentioned information. 
I am sure there is some .NET API but which one is that I am unsure.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067240/user-logged-into-remote-machine or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212155/how-to-get-logged-on-users-with-their-status-on-remote-machine

Comment: The first link is not of use to me beause I am unable to see System.Management.ConnectionOptions class in my intellisense and the second link is also not useful because I am unable to see 'ManagementScope' class.

Comment: I have tried all the available answers from this site but all of them end up with the following exception, "RPC server is unavailable". Where I can successfully log on them using remote desktop viewer.

Answer (score 10):

This query give to you all the logged users

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query= new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE Loaded = True");
```

You also have other parameters like `LastUseTime` into [Win32_UserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is used for local computer. Can I use it somehow for remote machines?

Comment: All classes in the System.Management namespace work with single or multiple computers in a domain. You need to use the proper constructor that specifies *where* to search (local, remote computer, multiple computers) etc.

Comment: How can we get username from this?

Comment: This is not reliable. Sometimes it returns users that are not logged in.