# Get total logins from getalluers() forms authentication method

Tags: c#

Is there a quick way to get the total number of logins per each user when using forms authentication `getAllUsers` function?

I tired to modify the stored procedure but I messed things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this for local machine:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query= new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile WHERE Loaded = True");
```

You can get some help from here as well: [User logged into remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067240/user-logged-into-remote-machine)

Comment: Hi R.T., thanks for your reply. I was hoping to be able to use some of the pre-existing stored procedures created for Forms authentication. All I am thinking to display is the number of logins for users on my web application, not on my machine. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @brillox:- If its a asp.net website then you can use `User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User` or `Membership.GetUser()`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @brillox:- Also I m not very sure if there is any existing stored procedure to get that. I have seen people using only this technique to get the list of logged in users. Also if you want to get the list of all active users who are logged in to  your website then you can check how many `sessions` you have open